# `Extra argument method in call` in Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to send the following data using Alamofire version 3 and Swift 3. And the error that I get is `Extra argument method in call`.
Here is what I have done so far:

```
struct userGoalServerConnection {
        let WeightsUserGoal_POST = "http://api.umchtech.com:3000/AddWeightsGoal"


    }


struct wieghtsUserGoal {
        let id : Int
        let token : String
        let data : [ String : String ]
    }


    func syncInitialUserGaolValuesWithServer (userID : Int , userToken : String ){
        let serverConnection = userGoalServerConnection()
        let weightValue = wieghtsUserGoal.init(id: userID,
                                               token: userToken,
                                               data: ["weight_initial":"11","weight_end":"11","weight_difference":"11","calories_deficit":"11","difficulties":"11","weight_loss_week":"11","start_date":"2016-12-12","end_date":"2016-12-23","days_needed":"11"])

        Alamofire.request(userGoalServerConnection.WeightsUserGoal_POST, method:.post, parameters: weightValue, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:nil).responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
                print(response.response as Any) // URL response
                print(response.result.value as Any)   // result of response serialization
        }
```

I am quite new to this so please dont mind if my question is a little bit too noob. I have gone through similar questions here but they did not help me out figuring where am i making a mistake :)

Comment: You are passing `weightValue` as post param in request, it can't be. if you are using `JSONEncoding` then pass type of `Parameters` object.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `weightValue` as `POST` param in request, it can't be. If you are using `JSONEncoding` then pass type of `Parameters` object.

```
let params: Parameters = [
        "Key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass dictionary type a alamofire request, you cannot post a struct type.

you can send `[String : String]`, `[String : Any]` etc in a Alamofire request

You can try this way out

```
 let WeightsUserGoal_POST = "http://api.umchtech.com:3000/AddWeightsGoal"




func Serialization(object: AnyObject)  -> String{
    do {
        let stringData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: [])
        if let string = String(data: stringData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8){
            return string
        }
    }catch _ {

    }
    return "{\"element\":\"jsonError\"}"
}




func syncInitialUserGaolValuesWithServer (userID : Int , userToken : String ){


let data = ["weight_initial":"11","weight_end":"11","weight_difference":"11","calories_deficit":"11","difficulties":"11","weight_loss_week":"11","start_date":"2016-12-12","end_date":"2016-12-23","days_needed":"11"] as! [String : String]
        let dataSerialized = Serialization(object: data as AnyObject)
        let param = ["id" : userID,
                     "token" : userToken,
        "data" : dataSerialized ]


  Alamofire.request(WeightsUserGoal_POST, method: .post, parameters: param ,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
            print(response.response as Any) // URL response
            print(response.result.value as Any)   // result of response serialization
        }
    }
```